# isc-dhcp-server6 not giving out IPv6 static IPs to Netplan in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dhcp

I have one Ubuntu 18.04 server using /etc/network/interface and it can get its static ip from isc-dhcp-server and server6.

```
host Syslog {
         hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:5e:28:59;
         # fixed-address6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe5e:2859;
         fixed-address6 fd00:192:168:1::100;
}
```

The other Ubuntu 18.04 servers only get ipV4 static ip.  They don't get ipv6.  I put in the static commands and they get both addresses.

sudo systemctl -l status isc-dhcp-server and isc-dhcp-server6 have no errors other than.

```
Oct 29 16:46:53 pridns dhcpd[1989]: Solicit message from fe80::20c:29ff:fed5:81f8 port 546, transaction ID 0x3B94CD00
Oct 29 16:46:53 pridns dhcpd[1989]: Unable to pick client address: no IPv6 pools on this shared network
Oct 29 16:46:53 pridns dhcpd[1989]: Sending Advertise to fe80::20c:29ff:fed5:81f8 port 546
```

These are on each server.  The servers are VMs in VMWare 6.  I am going to check the firewall on VMWare to see if something is block but since /etc/network/interface works.  I can't believe it is blocked.